# Ionic - Get file from audio recorded with cordova plugin media

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I'm use ionic with [cordova-plugin-media](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media) to record audio and i want upload the audio recorded to server using [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) but i dont know how to get file from Media. I just try this:

Controller:

```
$scope.itemOnLongPress = function (id) {;
            myMedia = new Media("./sound/recorded.wav");
            myMedia.startRecord();
}

$scope.itemOnTouchEnd = function (id) {
    myMedia.stopRecord();
    myMedia.play();
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(myMedia.src,
        // success callback; generates the FileEntry object needed to convert to Base64 string
        function (fileEntry) {
            // convert to Base64 string
            function win(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                    var obj = evt.target.result; // this is your Base64 string
                    alert(obj);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            };
            var fail = function (evt) {};
            fileEntry.file(win, fail);
        },
        // error callback
        function () {
            alert('fail');
        }
    );
```

All time i getting "fail" from event, i try use some prefix like: "/sdcard/recorded.wav","file:///sound/recorded.wav","documents://recorded.wav" but everytime same error...

anyone know how i can get this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally i use cordova plugin (cordova-file-transfer) for do it and to get file i use:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY,0,function(filesystem) {
   var file = filesystem.root.toUrl;
   /*and need remove file:// from path so..*/
   file = file.slice(7)
}
```

I Hope this helps someone, i wasted a lot time with this sh*t.